# Different time measurements with MPI

Tags: c, time, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

I am getting different time measurements every time I run my MPI application. I am measuring time like this:

```
MPIt1 = MPI_Wtime();

// do work

MPIt2 = MPI_Wtime();
MPIelapsed = MPIt2 - MPIt1;
```

The behavior is same, with or without `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);`. The result of the program, of course, is correct every time the executable runs.

Check the extreme difference I got for a 5x5 matrix:

```
0.00025 seconds // first run
0.10728 seconds // second run
```

Moreover, the problem is occurring with larger matrices, like this 2000x2000:

```
0.55996 seconds // first run
0.83657 seconds // second run
```

Am I measuring the time in a wrong way? Or is this a knowing issue with MPI? Note that the time is reported only from the master node.

I am running the program in another computer, where I have logged in with `ssh`. I recall getting faster execution when I was actually sitting in that computer. I am the only user logged in:

```
gsamaras@pythagoras:~/konstantis/cholesky$ who
gsamaras my internet connection
gsamaras@pythagoras:~/konstantis/cholesky$
```

---

*EDIT* with many runs:

```
1.6035
0.422967
1.53891
0.347107
0.761991
1.22824
0.934829
0.45618
0.794225
0.554099
1.09323
0.421858
0.621015
0.889867
0.613867
0.459144
2.02273
0.67689
2.2390
1.0448
0.751333
```

---

*EDIT*_2

1. I got the timings, by calling the program many times in a run.sh.
2. I am running the program in **one** machine, with 4 cores.
3. I am using [MPICH2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPICH2).

Comment: Since you are logging into the other machine via `ssh`, are you sure there are no other resource intensive programs running? The startup time for MPI can vary a lot, make sure to place barriers just before each of the two measurement points for more stable measurements. Also, two measurements are not a lot, could you give some hints of what it looks like for 10-20 repetitions?

Comment: The barrier won't change anything, I tried it. But, it's a good tip. That's what I thought, but I am alone. Wish I could check it though. You mean to run the code 15 times and report the time? @Patrick

Comment: Yes. This way you can see if the variance is only in the first run or if the runtime has a large variance across many repeated runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a colleague and Patrick I concluded that:

1. The startup time for MPI can vary a lot.
2. Relatively small execution times are not trust-worthy and may vary a
   lot.